# Real Analysis Proof: Corollary of Intermediate Value Thereom

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, proof-explanation

I have recently picked up Patrick Fitzpatrick's *Advanced Calculus : A Course In Mathematical Analysis* and have come across a minor roadblock not too far into it.

> ***Proposition 1.3:*** Let $c$ be a positive number. Then there is a positive number whose square is $c$.
>
> ***17.*** *(Outline and proof of Proposition 1.3)* Define
>   $$
>  S \equiv \{x \mid x \in \mathbb{R}, x \geq 0, x^2 < c\}.
> $$
>
> 1. Show that $c+1$ is an upper bound for $S$ and therefore, by the Completeness Axiom, $S$ has a least upper bound that we denote by $b$.
> 2. Show that if $b^2 > c$, then we can choose a suitably small positive number $r$ such that $b-r$ is also an upper bound for $S$, thus contradicting the choice of $b$ as the *least* upper bound of $S$.
> 3. Show that if $b^2 < r$, then we can choose a suitably small positive numbers $r$ such that $b+r$ belongs to $S$, thus contradicting the choice of $b$ as *an* upper bound of $S$.
> 4. Use parts (2) and (3) and the Positivity Axioms for $\mathbb{R}$ to conclude that $b^2 = c$.

The proof in the text is by contradiction since 
 $\ b^2 < c $ and $\ b^2 > c $ are false while $\ b^2 =c $ is the only true solution (unique).

> First suppose that $b^2 < c$. We will choose a small positive number $r$ such that $(b+r)^2 < c$ is also less than $c$. Thus the number $b+r$ which is larger than $b$, belongs to $S$, contradicting the choice of $b$ as an upper bound for $S$. Hence, it cannot be the case that $b^2 < c$. To see how to choose such a number $r$, observe that if $r$ is any positive number less than $1$,
>   $$
>   (b+r)^2
>  = b^2 + 2rb + r^2
>  < b^2 + r(2b+1)
>  = c-(c-b^2) + r(2b + 1)
> $$

What I am having issues grasping is:

How is it that $b+r$ creates a contradiction for $b$ being an upper bound when $b$ was said to the least upper bound?

How is it that the polynomial expansion turned into $b^2 + r(2b+1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Let $b'$ be an upper bound of $S$. This means that 
   $$x \leq b' \quad \text{for all } x \in S \; .$$
   Now $b$ is the least upper bound $S$. This means that $b$ is an upper bound of $S$ and for any upper bound $b'$ of $S$, we have $b \leq b'$.
   You have showed, that under the assumption $b^2 < c$, there exists a $r > 0$, such that $b + r \in S$. Since $b$ is an upper bound, we have $x \leq b$ for all $x \in S$. By taking $x = b + r \in S$, we have $b + r \leq b$, a contradiction!
2. Since $0 < r < 1$: 
   $$b^2 + 2rb + r^2 = b^2 + r(2b + \underbrace{r}_{< 1}) < b^2 + r(2b+1)$$

Answer (score 0):

i) it's a contradiction because the existence of $b+r$ shows that $b$ cannot be the least upper bound

ii) the term $r^2$ was estimated by $r^2 < r $ which is true if $0< r <1$.